# i want to perform print funtioanlity in react-data-table-component

Tags: reactjs

I am using the react-data-table-component and have added a print functionality to it. However, when I add more rows and columns to the dataTable, it only shows 12 columns and cuts off the rest. Can anyone help me resolve this issue? I have tried multiple solutions, including using the react-dataTable-extension package, but it seems to be deprecated.

Comment: Post your code in the question

Comment: same thing I needs  to implement but react-dataTable plugin has been deprecated so now I think we can use jspdf, export-table-to-excel I guess for pdf and excel. But do let  know if you found any approach